# Using rspec to test rails app on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails, production

I am using rspec to test my rails app on production. As I know the structure of rspec is fix

```
spec
|- controllers
|- features
  |- production (I need to put is here to run test)
|- mailers
|- models
|- support
|- spec_helper.rb
|- production (I want to put my new folder here)
```

I want to add new folder to contain all test for production which is sub-folder of spec, but I cannot run test if I do like this. 
(NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #)

Now, I am placing the production folder as sub-folder of features to be able to run test.

Do you know how to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what.... you don't run tests on production. You run tests in the test environment.

Comment: @sevenseacat I want to use capybara to test some flow on Production website to make sure functions work after I deployed

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an issue with folder nesting. That error tends to pop up when you haven't included the correct files. Do you have `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of your spec file? Also, have you included capybara in your gemfile/spec helper file? `visit` comes from capybara, so you need it to use that method.

Comment: I added the inline `require 'spec_helper'` and also had capybara gem. But it only work if I place production folder inside features.